# Short story : angels show their creations to God in order to populate the world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story that I studied in high school and I can't remember the name. It was the story of God, creating the world with his angels. They showed him a lot of ideas, that he accepted or not. Until one of them showed him some kind of species, in between monkeys and angels.

This species was meant to be intelligent. At first, God refused the creation of this species, as he considered it was too dangerous for the peaceful world he wanted. In the end, the temptation was too high and he created humans.

Things that I am sure about:

- The world doesn't exist yet.
- The angels show kind of drawings to God.
- Some creatures are declined.
- They have a good laugh when one of the angels presented the elephant.
- Same thing with the giraffe.
- At first, humans are declined because considered too dangerous and not peaceful enough.
- At the end of the day, all the angels showed their creations and God is alone. He is too tempted and creates humans like "well, we'll see what happens".

Comment: Can you remember if this is intended as a fantastical setting about the creation of humans or is it actually meant to be a religious story? If the latter, it would be [off topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10186/58193) I'm afraid but the line is a bit blurry with this.

Comment: It was a fantastical setting. It was in a short stories book with a lot of other topics. And it was not written in a religious style.

Comment: Could it be Gaiman's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_Mysteries ? There are some similarities (even if the main plot seems kinda different).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but nope. The world is not created yet. I can remember that they had a good laugh when one of the angel introduced to God the elephant.

Comment: May I ask how did you study this story? On the internet, in a book or printed pages etc?

Comment: @pigwidgeon it was in a book, a collection of stories. I think I was in high school so 8-6 years ago, but it was way older than that. I am French so it could be either a french or an english-speaker author. And I studied it in literature classes.

Comment: might be something by Mark Twain

Comment: @Gnudiff i've looked all of the stories by Mark Twain i could find on the internet and some have similarities in the plot but not they're all very different in the way of being told.

Comment: @LeaG yes, I had a look at the stories too, the one I had in mind -- Letters from Earth --- was released posthumously so it is not on Gutenberg yet. But it deals with 3 angels discussing God's creations (and Lucifer being exiled to Earth then sends specific letters about humans to his other angel friends), rather than doing it themselves...

Comment: Somehow it makes me think of Bernard Werber. I'll check tonight.

Comment: OP posted to https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15148/139 later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Could it be "La Creazione" by Dino Buzzati, from "Il Colombre" (in French: "La Création", from "Le K")

I only have the text in French, but here are the relevant parts (translation provided by myself, feel free to correct it):

They have a good laugh when one of the angels presented the elephant:

> Un éclat de rire général et bruyant accueillit le dessin
> de l’éléphant. La longueur de son nez semblait excessive,
> grotesque même. L’inventeur rétorqua qu’il ne s’agissait
> pas d’un nez mais d’un organe très spécial, pour lequel il
> proposait le nom de proboscide ou trompe."

> A general burst of laughter welcomed the design of the elephant. The length of its nose seemed excessive, grotesque even. The inventor replied that it was no nose but a very special organ for which he was suggesting the name of proboscis or trunk.

At first, humans are declined because considered too dangerous and not peaceful enough:

> — Oui, ô Seigneur, confirma l’importun. Il s’agit,
> modestie mise à part, d’une invention formidable. Ceci
> serait l’homme et cela la femme. Indépendamment de
> l’aspect physique, qui, je l’admets, est discutable, j’ai
> cherché à les faire de telle façon qu’ils soient, pardonne-
> moi ma hardiesse, à ta ressemblance, ô Très-Haut. Ce
> sera, dans toute la création, le seul être doué de raison,
> l’unique qui pourra se rendre compte de ton existence,
> l’unique qui saura t’adorer. En ton honneur il bâtira des
> temples grandioses et il livrera des guerres terriblement
> meurtrières.
> — Aïe, aïe, aïe ! Tu veux dire que ce serait un
> intellectuel ? fit le Tout-Puissant. Fais-moiconfiance, mon
> fils, non, pas d’intellectuels. L’univers en est exempt, par
> chance, jusqu’à présent. Et j’espère qu’il restera tel
> jusqu’à la fin des millénaires. "

> "Yes, great Lord", he confirmed. "It consists
> in, false modesty aside, a marvellous invention. This would be the man, and this, the woman. Independently of the physical aspect, which is, I admit it, questionable, my aim was to make them as such as they were in your image and likeness, pardon my boldness, Most High. It will be, in all of Creation, the only being endowed with reason, the only one which will be able to realize your existence, the only who will aodre you. In your name he will build wonderful temples and lead woefully deadly wars."
> "My, my! Do you mean it will be an intellectual?" said the Almighty. "Trust me, my son, no intellectual. The universe is thankfully devoid of it, and I hope it will stay the same for millenia."

At the end of the day, all the angels showed their creations and god is alone. He is too tempted and creates humans like "well, we'll see what happens":

> L’homme ! quelle idée folle, quel dangereux caprice. Mais
> dans le fond quel jeu fascinant, quelle terrible tentation.
> Après tout, peut-être cela en valait-il la peine. Bah !
> advienne que pourra. Et puis, en période de création, on
> pouvait bien se montrer optimiste.
> « Allons, donne-moi ça », dit le Tout-Puissant en
> saisissant le fatal projet.
> Et il y apposa sa signature."

> Man! Such a foolich idea, such a dangerous whim. And all the same, such a fascinating game, such a terrible temptation. After all, perhaps it could be worth it. Well, come what may. And in a time of creation, one could be optimistic.
> "Here, give me this" said the Almighty, taking the fatal project.
> And he signed.

Comment: YEEES ! This is this one ! Thank you so much I am looking for it since a looooong time

Comment: @LeaG You're welcome :) Small question though, should I try to translate the french parts in english, so as to prove my point even further ?

Comment: as French is my first language I don't need translation but I don't know about the other users. I guess that if they can see the author and the name of the novel it's ok.